# Run-time error while sorting doubly linked list

Tags: c, sorting

I have written a program which cretates 12 tables with random capacities. I want to sort that doubly linked list by insertion. Although the code was compiled with no error, I got run-time error. I have no idea why. Is there anyone can help me?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 12

struct Table {
      int capacity;
      struct Table *next;
      struct Table *prev;
};

typedef void (*table_func_pnt) (struct Table *table);
struct Table *add_random_number(struct Table *head);
void insertion_sort(struct Table **head);

void list_tables(struct Table *head, table_func_pnt func);
void print_capacity(struct Table *table);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      srand(time(0));

      struct Table *list = NULL;

     for(int i = 0; i<MAX; ++i){
          list = add_random_number(list);
     }

     list_tables(list,print_capacity);
     printf("\n");


     insertion_sort(&list);


     list_tables(list,print_capacity);

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

struct Table *add_random_number(struct Table *head){

        struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(struct Table));
        table->capacity = 2 + rand() % 10;
        table->next = head;

        return table;
}

void list_tables(struct Table *head, table_func_pnt func)
{
        while(head){
            func(head);
            head = head->next;
        }
}

void print_capacity(struct Table *table)
{
        printf("%d ",table->capacity);
}

void insertion_sort(struct Table **head)
{
        int n;

        struct Table *curr;
        curr = *head;

        if(curr->next == NULL)
            return;

        struct Table *ptr;
        struct Table *temp;
        curr = curr->next;

        while(curr != NULL){

                n = 0;
                ptr = curr;
                temp = curr->prev;
                curr = curr->next;

                 while(temp != NULL && temp->capacity > ptr->capacity){
                        n++ ;
                        temp = temp->prev;
                 }if(n){
                        ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
                        if(ptr->next != NULL)
                        ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;

                        if(temp == NULL){
                            temp = *head;
                            ptr->prev = NULL;
                            ptr->next = temp;
                            ptr->next->prev =ptr;
                            *head = ptr;
                        }else{
                           temp = temp->next;
                           temp->prev->next = ptr;
                           ptr->prev = temp->prev;
                           temp->prev = ptr;
                           ptr->next = temp;
                       }
                }

       }

}
```

Comment: Try running in a debugger, to locate where the crash happens.

Comment: If you want a doubly linked list, you need something like `if(head!=NULL){head->prev=table;}` in function `add_random_number()`

Comment: You are right @francis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get runtime errors from `insertion_sort()` (but not before) is because you have forgotten to set the `prev` field of the linked list. So it's actually a singly linked list, and the simple parse `list_tables()` works. But in `insertion_sort()` you start using the uninitialised `prev` pointers, resulting in a crash.

Comment: @Rinzler - an alternative approach would be a sort that only uses the next pointers, then after the sort is done, traversing through the sorted list to set the previous pointers. I'm not sure if this would be significantly faster or worth the effort. If speed was an issue (very large list), then a bottom up merge sort would be much faster.